# old 230 volt transformer style arc welder on an old square d 125 amp panel

Tags: electrical

I have a an old 230 volt S.D.LEE arc welder (that I can not find any info about) printed on the front is says "PRI volts 230 max OCV 78 arc volts 25 PRI amps 65.7 SEC amps 230 temp rise 115c 60 cycles single phase model 110-085"
I am not sure what that means but I think it means at the welders max setting I need 230 volts at 65.7 amps?

[image]
<sup>Click for larger View</sup>

I rent an old house that looks like its haunted it has an old square D panel 125 amp QO combination panel (also don't know what that means really) lots of empty slots but the combined amps not including the main shut off is 165 amps I think I need a 70 amp breaker for the welder (not sure).

Can I safely add one? If so, what conduit should I use with the 70 amp breaker to run my welder about 45 feet from the panel?

[image] 
[image] 
[image]
[image]
<sup>Click for larger View</sup>

I really don't want to burn the house down, my landlord probably wouldn't like that either.

Comment: Since you're renting, you should have the landlord hire an Electrician.  Doing electrical (or most any) work in a property you don't own, is usually frowned upon.

Comment: Your S.D.LEE welder was probably a private label built by the Century company (Century was a pioneer in infinite amp control, as the welder advertises on the face). That may help you find more information. A detail photo of the power connector(s) would help also. Electrical work will require the approval of your landlord, at the minimum. Oh, and a little google work shows: Century was purchased in 2003 by Lincoln Electric http://www.lincolnelectric.com/en-us/company/Pages/company-history.aspx

Comment: the landlord says I can do whatever I want he plans to tear the house down in a few years

Comment: what connectors would you like a photo of?

Comment: What plug is on the end?  Are there two?  Is there a rating plate where the cords enter the unit?  Look up the plug type at the Digital Museum of Plugs and Sockets.

Answer (score 1):

While the panel is rated 125 amp, you have a 100 amp service. You also have an electric dryer and water heater in addition to the usual lights and outlets. Adding a 66 amp load to all of this is definitely overloading the service.

If you went ahead and installed this welder, you won't burn down the house (at least not from electrical loads, from welding is another story) but you would get nuisance tripping. Every time you struck an arc, the lights would dim. The resulting voltage drop could damage electronic equipment such as computers and TVs, as well as anything else with electronics, which is virtually everything these days.

Comment: thank you for your answer but what if I turn off the breakers for the dryer, hot water tank, and anything else I can? I am the only one living in the house I could have everything off wile welding (outside)

Comment: A whole house surge protector can help here.  And nothing says the dryer/water heater need to be on when welding.

Comment: I don't see how a whole house surge protector is going to help prevent tripping the breaker if he runs the welder and the dryer at the same time.

Comment: The "damage to electronics" would be from spikes, not an overcurrent trip.  A 250 amp service won't change that.

Comment: if all the breakers are off will I be able to run the welder or is it simply too much for this old panel?

Comment: the plug for the welder is two horizontal blades and a ground pin only one plug I put together a plug adapter to plug it into a dryer socket but that is only 30 amps

Comment: The NEC and probably any other electric code has very specific methods for calculating service loads. It makes allowances for non-concurrent loads and duty cycles, so it's not like you have to add up the max. current draw of everything. Still, the welder will kick you over 100A. If you turned off the breaker of your heater and fridge and didn't use anything else while welding, you could possibly be able to work without too much nuisance tripping, but there is no way this installation would ever meet code.

Comment: If you are not welding at maximum amps (out) it won't draw maximum amps (in.) I've done a fair bit of welding with a 225 amp rig and rarely go much above 100 amps for typical welding jobs...

Comment: Interestingly, the original plug configuration you describe is a variant of 30Amp 230V plug. I'm fairly sure that 50 amp is as high as plug-in's normally go - beyond that it's all hardwire. A picture of the original plug would help to be sure.